# Android nullable annotation not recognized in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations

Android source code suggests that `findViewById` can return null:

```
@Nullable
public final <T extends View> T findViewById(@IdRes int id) {
    if (id == NO_ID) {
        return null;
    }
    return findViewTraversal(id);
}
```

But when calling it from Kotlin, compiler doesn't complain about nullability when using this way:

```
private lateinit var swipeRefreshLayout: SwipeRefreshLayout
...
swipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh)
```

As I can guess, this `Nullable` annotation is from android pacakge and there are also other `Nullable` annotations, that Kotlin does recognize well. Is it Kotlin/IDE related issue or should Android team do something about this?

Comment: `findViewById()` will return you `T!` meaning it would be **nullable** and you've to explicitly handle it like declaring `SwipeRefreshLayout?`.

Comment: Oh, thanks, missed T. I should explicitly provide SwipeRefreshLayout? to findViewById.

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById` is using generics. We explicitly provide the type it should return. If we rewrite the init line, compiler would complain about nullability.

```
swipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout?>(R.id.swiperefresh)
```